# Anotação @Get não funciona no controller

Tags: java, vraptor, annotation

Estou tentando customizar minha url com @Get no Vraptor 4, porém o mesmo não é reconhecido,

Segue o controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class OlaController {
       @Inject Result result;

       @Get("/ola")
       public void digaOla(){
         result.include("mensagem", "Olá, VRaptor 4!");
       }
    }
```

No navegador aparece o erro 404, porém sem a anotação a página é exibida normalmente, existe alguma biblioteca ou algo que eu não importei?

Segue o meu pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
        <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-RC3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Segue o meu web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Estou usando o servidor wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

Para customizar sua URL no Vraptor você precisa definir o caminho na anotação `@Path`

Exemplo:

```
@Get
@Path("/listar")
public void listar() {..}
```

Mais explicações sobre o `Path`:

[Javadoc Vraptor](http://www.vraptor.org/javadoc/br/com/caelum/vraptor/Path.html)

Comment: Dessa forma também não está carregando a view.